# Servicestack OrmLite "where exists" subquery

Tags: subquery, servicestack, exists, ormlite-servicestack

No matter how hard I tried I couldn't make it work and I'm not sure if it is possible.
I want to select all clients who have at least one order.

The first thing I tried was db.Exists as following:

`SqlExpression<Client> exp = OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.SqlExpression<Client>();
exp.Where(x => Db.Exists<Order>(z => z.ClientId == x.Id));`

but I get the following error

> variable 'x' of type '[assembly].Client' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined`

Second try was using Join and SelectDistinct:

`SqlExpression<Client> exp = OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.SqlExpression<Client>();
ev.Join<Client, Order>((b, a) => b.Id == a.ClientId)
.SelectDistinct(x => new { x.Id, x.ClientNumber, x.ClientNameName});`

Although not optimal it worked, up to the moment when I needed paging for the result set through

`ev.Limit(skip:((request.Page-1) * request.PageSize), rows:request.PageSize)`

When using Limit the distinct logically get ignored in building the query, so I get now duplicate Clients.

Is there any other way, or in general is there away to handle subqueries in OrmLite?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Anyone any thought in this!

Answer (score 1):

ServiceStack OrmLite (currently at 4.0.x) does not have support for subqueries.

If you look at the 4.0.x docs , there is no discussion of subqueries. JOIN support has been added recently, but for advanced SQL, you need to [write it yourself](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#performing-custom-queries).

Honestly, at a certain point of complexity, SQL is more readable than advanced ORM/LINQ-style queries.

Comment: FYI, as of [4.0.44](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2015/release-notes.md#nested-typed-sub-sqlexpressions), you can have an SqlExpression in a Sql.In clause.  You can rewrite your subquery as a "Where ClientId IN (Select Client Id from Client Inner Join Orders)".  Can't speak to performance though.